# Set JCS log level to ERROR - log4j

Tags: java, caching, logging, log4j, jcs

I have implemented `JCS` in my J2ee application which uses log4j for logging.

**My Requirement**

Set the application `rootLogger` in `DEBUG` level and `jcs` logs in `ERROR` mode.

**What is tried**

Tried the following in `log4j` properties

```
log4j.category.org.apache.common.jcs=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.common.jcs=ERROR
```

But nothing is affecting the logging.

Whenever the cache access happens, it logs a bunch of `returning first node` messages.

Note : I am using the latest JCS `commons-jcs-core-2.0-beta-1.jar`

This is my complete log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# Use Console Appender for development
 log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %-5p - %m%n

log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.common.jcs=ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed an **"s"** in **commons**. Correcting it solved my problem.

**Solution**

Both the below statements can be used to configure JCS log level in log4j.

```
log4j.category.org.apache.commons.jcs=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.jcs=ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

JCS has a dependency on commons-logging for logging, and not log4j. Hence, log4j configurations won't matter unless you redirect commons-logging to log4j. To do that, create a file named `commons-logging.properties` and add the following in that.

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jLogger
```